# Java option counter

Tags: java, netbeans, counting

Let's say I have 6 options and 4 people that can choose any of these options.

there are 4 variables (int) one for each person, they can choose one option.

two or more people can select the same option.

how can I count how many times each option has been selected without doing a bunch of if statements?

Also, I'm not allowed to use data structures.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have now? The community is not for answering homework questions. Please show your effort in answering the question first. Also if you are not allowed to use any data structures then the only way to do this is doing a bunch of if statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the answers using primes p_1  to p_6. An unique prime p for each option. You start with a 'memory' integer m. Each time an user u selects an option i you multiply your 'memory' int with the corresponding option prime m = m* p_i. At any given time you can find selected options as the prime decomposition of m. This approach does not allow you to recover the order of the choices though. If that is important too you could alternatively code the user with the primes and their answers with as the factors m= p_1^(option user 1) * p_2^(option user 2) * ... * p_n ^(option user n). Anyway your choice depends a bit on what you want to do with the answers and whether you want to introduce more users or rather more options.
I hope this might put you in a useful direction for you assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [hashmap](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_hashmap.asp) to store the individual user along with their option. Then iterate through the hashmap to determine how often a specific option has been selected.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> selections = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to mention, this is for programming class and I'm not allowed to use java data structures. (Just edited the post).